# finding matching pattern, performing calculations and shifting the columns of file

Tags: sed, awk

I need help to format below file with some calculation for a particular row having some pattern

```
hnt     1       454     454
gft         10          8844        8853
step        2       23      24
str     10     Check sum(00244-00240)   420 434
dert        03      14      16
ghh     33     Check sum(12366-12361)   8008    8046
```

I need to have four column file by performing subtraction for the row having text "check sum". 
I wish to remove the text "Check sum" and then subtract the numbers given in (  ). For e.g. (00244-00240) will be subtracted and will be having value  '4' and this '4' will be added to left column which has the value '10'. 
so now this value will become '14'. After this calculation the other value on that row will shift left column wise. Thus making four columns table instead of six columns

The desired output is

```
hnt     1       454     454
gft         10          8844        8853
step        2       23      24
str     14      420     434
dert        03      14      16
ghh     38      8008        8046
```

I am new to shell scrip and appreciate your help to get above desired output using awk or sed or both. I am also ok if this can be achieved without using this awk and sed and by using other command in unix shell script

Answer (score 1):

Perl can do the parsing and the addition:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\s+Check sum\((\d+)([+-]\d+)\)/$1+$2+$3/e' file
```

```
hnt     1       454     454
gft         10          8844        8853
step        2       23      24
str     14   420 434
dert        03      14      16
ghh     38   8008    8046
```

If you want the output to look prettier, pipe the result through `column -t`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one liner:

```
sed "s/Check//;s/sum//;s/(//;s/)//" filename|awk '/-/{sub(/-/," ");for (i=1;i<=NF;i++);{calc=$3-$4;$2=$2+calc;$3="";$4=""}}1'
```

Note:
This answer does not retain the original white-spaces for the rows having calculation performed